# OpenSSL does not match Python hashlib

Tags: python, openssl, sha, pyopenssl

I am new to using the OpenSSL library and I cannot get its output to match the output from python's crypto libraries. Below is an example.

Python Code:

```
import hmac

secret = "asdf1234"
string = '{"request"}'

hmac.new(secret, string, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
    '92904f1b3c210a4fb19f476c19f24452717e85329aa9ffaba4a5fbe1111c2e3fa7f5a5fb35fdc58b3d158f5f886c3d02'
```

OpenSSl:

```
echo -n {"request"} | openssl dgst -sha384 -hmac asdf1234 -hex

(stdin)= 4c3d525b8a7095b9063a3bd974e56f0a5872399365912297d6ee18e400d2b55d0142395ba5fb4f33655ceca209ba9570
```

What am I doing wrong? Is either implementation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the openssl output, the Python string should be `'{request}'` rather than `'{"request"}'`.

```
import hmac
import hashlib
secret = "asdf1234"
string = '{request}'

hmac.new(secret, string, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
```

yields

```
'4c3d525b8a7095b9063a3bd974e56f0a5872399365912297d6ee18e400d2b55d0142395ba5fb4f33655ceca209ba9570'
```

Or, if you want the openssl command to match the Python output, use

```
echo -n '{"request"}' | openssl dgst -sha384 -hmac asdf1234 -hex
```

which yields

```
(stdin)= 92904f1b3c210a4fb19f476c19f24452717e85329aa9ffaba4a5fbe1111c2e3fa7f5a5fb35fdc58b3d158f5f886c3d02
```

---

After all, the inputs have to match for the outputs to have a chance at matching:

```
% echo -n {"request"}
{request}
```

and

```
>>> print('{"request"}')
{"request"}
```